# How to simulate a circuit based on dac5578 (I2C TO 8 Channel DAC)

Tags: circuit-design, i2c, simulation, dac

I designed a circuit based on DAC5578 from TI and I want to simulate it.
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: yes, that's possible. What is your precise question? Have you looked at the things with the word "simulation" in it on TI's product page?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want a testing software that contain this component, I didn't find it in TINA_TI